# Optimal solutions of x and y for $\max_{x,y}~\min (f(x,y),~g(x,y))$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Can someone help me to find analytical solutions for optimal values of $x$ and $y$ which satisfy the following optimization problem?

\begin{align}
\max_{x,y}~\min & \left[a\left(\frac{1-x}{2-x}\right),~b\left(x+\frac{2y}{1-y}\right)\right]\\
& 0\leq x\leq 1 ~~\text{and}~~ 0\leq y\leq 1 \\
& a,b\geq 0
\end{align}

Comment: You want to look at three different cases: where you maximize $a\frac{1-x}{2-x}$, where you maximize $bx+b\frac{2y}{1-y}$, and where the two are equal. If they are not equal over $0\leq x,y\leq 1$, you ignore that case. But otherwise, you pick the smallest of the three.

Answer (score 0):

we have, $$ \frac{1-x}{2-x} \geq 0$$ and $$ x+ \frac{2y}{1-y}\geq 0 $$
for any $x$ and $y$ in $[0,1]$. Thus the $\min$ is attained for  $a=0$ or $b=0$ if you are taking minimization over $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $a=0$ or $b=0$ is a special case, but the problem should be solved over $x$ and $y$ for general $a$ and $b$.